# green sludge floating

Tags: dry-hop, mold, americanipa

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3nIWsUoDjs2RVlsZ3FnaWdYRjQ/edit?usp=docslist_api

I am brewing a double IPA. The beer is in the secondary and has been there for  10 days. I recorded 7.8% alc when I transferred it. I just noticed this green sludge in the top forming. I am dry hoping with an ounce of pellets in cheese cloth. There doesn't seem to be hair growing in the sludge. It's this hopsludge or mold? Thanks.

The picture I'm including in the link makes it look brown but it looks more green in person.

Answer (score 4):

It's likely that your pellets had some very finely chopped hops in them. They have escaped the bag and triggered a bit of bubble formation in the beer, bringing them to the top of the beer. Hopefully they'll stick to the fermenter when you rack or bottle.